# Plotting in python with rows

Tags: python, plot

I have a plot of an array of numbers ranging from 0 to 10. These numbers all represent a certain element of height. When I run this plot I get a figure of a line graph. However, I would like to have rows. How is this possible? Thanks.

```
plt.plot(np.arange(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10),num_matches) 
ylim([0, 1000])
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume you mean a bar plot, so use bar:

```
plt.bar(np.arange(10),np.random.randint(0,1000,10)) 
plt.ylim([0, 1000])
```

[image: barplot]

Answer (score 0):

I think you're looking for a [Bar Plot](http://matplotlib.org/api/axes_api.html#matplotlib.axes.Axes.bar) or [Horizontal Bar Plot](http://matplotlib.org/api/axes_api.html#matplotlib.axes.Axes.barh)